# Is the unique morphism from the empty scheme $\operatorname{Spec}((0))$ to some other scheme $X$ smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is a very pedantic question, but

> Is the unique morphism from the empty scheme $\emptyset = \operatorname{Spec}((0))$ to some other scheme $X$ smooth?

Comment: Pedantic remark: The initial scheme has *underlying set* $\emptyset$, but *the scheme* is not $\emptyset$ in the sense of set theory. The initial scheme is $(\emptyset,\mathcal{O}_\emptyset)$, where $\mathcal{O}_\emptyset(\emptyset)=\{0\}$. Nevertheless, we denote it by $\emptyset$ and follow the common principle of forgetting forgetful functors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It doesn't matter which definition you choose, smoothness of $\emptyset \to X$ is satisfied for trivial reasons. More generally, any open immersion is smooth.